Vitest "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". Fonts files mocking
In my project I switch from jest tests to Vitest, and a problem has arisen: files with fonts and icons are not being mocking when I want to make a snapshot of component.
Before that, I processed them using moduleNameMapper, but this doesn't help in any way on Vitest. I tried a lot of different ways to solve this problem, but nothing helped me.
I tried to mock fonts and svg files like this in vite.config.ts.
test: {
 alias: [
      {
        find: /.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$/,
        replacement: resolve('./mocks/test-mock.js'),
      },
      {
        find: /.+\\.(css|scss|less|sass)$/,
        replacement: resolve('identity-obj-proxy'),
      },
   ],
}

Error is like this:
'SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' ❯ Object.<anonymous> node_modules/some-material-ui-library/styles/defaultTheme/fonts.js
